# Cannot retrieve data from firebase and its display no data from firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to retrieve profile details from firebase. But, not data retrieve. Can someone help me what is wrong with my code?

```
 Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUser() async {
var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("User")
    .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
    .get();
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the code instead of the photo! Then it'll be good to others!

Comment: I add the code but it said too many code thats why i put photo. im sorry. i will edit again

Comment: if the user is signed in currently, it returns user details, otherwise, it returns null, So, please check whether it's not or not before using it and also make sure whether the collection name is correct or not.

Comment: I use the same code to display user details on the homepage, the data is there. but when i use the same code on the profile page, the data is not displayed